# When a subview is displayed above the scroll view, it does not scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, addsubview

When a subview is displayed above the scroll view, it does not scroll.

My subview is displayed in the following way:

```
let reservationPopOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "reservationPopup") as! ReservationPopupViewController
        self.addChildViewController(reservationPopOverVC)
        reservationPopOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(reservationPopOverVC.view)
        reservationPopOverVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Then a subview (`reservationPopOverVC.view`) appears, but the main view'a scrolling below it does not work. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply disable the user interaction for the view:

```
reservationPopOverVC.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Comment: oh, thank you! It works! but I need using buttons of reservationPopOver. Can not I use the buttons in the subview while using the main view scrolling?

Comment: For that to work, you should disable the background view's user interaction (assuming you have one behind the buttons). It's all a matter of layout planning.

Comment: oh.. in my storyboard, `View>MainView>closeBtn`. so i create UIView: `View>ViewForScroll` and try `reservationPopOverVC.ViewForScroll.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`.. but It doen't work what I expected. I think I'm doing something wrong.